# JavaScript code runs once at the start than it stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Jvectormap Library to display world-wide Map. I have followed the tutorial from the official site [Getting started Tutorial](http://jvectormap.com/tutorials/getting-started/) to include the map in the HTML View File as follows:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">   
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="author" content="">
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">
     <title>Al Andulas</title>
     <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
     <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
     <link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom styles for VictorMap -->
     <link href="assets/css/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3" rel="stylesheet">  
     <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SP<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>T</a>
         </div>
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Main</a></li>
             <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a></li>
           </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
     </div> 
<div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row centered">
           <br><br>
           <div class="col-lg-12">    
           <div id="world-map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
           <!-- the Script that works only once -->
     <script>
     $(function(){
       $('#world-map').vectorMap({map: 'world_mill'});
     });   
     </script>
               </div>
           </div>
           </div>
       </div>  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
     ================================================== -->
     <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>   <script src="assets/js/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"></script>  
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js"></script>
     </body>
      </html>
```

First time I paste the code into the editor and view via the browser the map appears but when I refresh the page the map is not showing anymore on the site and therefore, I have to delete the JavaScript code and re paste it again:

```
 <script>
 $(function(){
   $('#world-map').vectorMap({map: 'world_mill'});
 });   
 </script>
```

what is the correct way to display the map permanently on the site.

Comment: Add that script into your Html page

Comment: the script is emended with the HTML after the Nav Section

Comment: @hamza are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Since that I am not an expert with Javascript Library, I think some how maybe the code needs to go to a js file and than call it from within the HTML.

Comment: @soviut, I am using Brackets.

Comment: @hamza I meant what errors does the browser console give. Press F12 in your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is placed wrong.

1. You shouldn't put a `<script>` inside a `<div>` tag
2. your script throws an error because you try to use jQuery before you include it.

   2.1. Bootstrap requires jQuery to run. So you need to include jQuery before bootstrap.

The correct order would be

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"></script>  
<script src="assets/js/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#world-map').vectorMap({map: 'world_mill'});
    });   
</script>
```

Now all that remains would be to ask yourself why you are including two versions of jQuery... That will end in problems - so I've thrown the older version out here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood the concept behind the correct use of the script which should be placed at the end of the page for faster loader and It will be called up in the HTML div Tag via the ID assigned it

Comment: You don't understand @hamza. The script is loaded after the other scripts because it needs the other scripts to run

Answer (score 0):

First answer is right.
But you can try next:

```
    $.getScript('assets/js/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js', function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#world-map').vectorMap({map: 'world_mill'});
    }, 90);
});
```